# Images to video in PHP with FFmpeg

Tags: php, image, video, ffmpeg

I got a terrible problem. I've been searching, and google-ing my whole day and can't find the answer to this problem..

I am trying to convert 5 pictures to video using FFmpeg in PHP. I have FFmpeg extension installed in my php.ini.

Trying running this command:

```
<?php
exec("ffmpeg -r 25 -qscale 2 -i %05d.jpg output.mp4");
?>
```

but it gives me a blank page with no errors or something. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: does the command works from command line with the user that executes the php script?

Comment: don't test stuff through php like that. it'll hide error messages. test your exec'd stuff from a real command line first, **THEN** wrap it in php. General things to check: is ffmpeg in that shell's path? does php have permissions to write that .mp4 file? Does it have permission to read the jpgs?

Comment: how to exec it from a real command line.. I run this code with XAMPP

Comment: ffmpeg is in C:/xampp/php/ext/

Comment: I had this old line for a similar propose: `ffmpeg.exe -y -r 15 -i "data\%%08d.png" -i "data\audio.mp3" -acodec copy -vcodec msmpeg4v2 -b 256k -r 15 "result.avi"` It would get all the PNG files from the data\ folder ranging from 00000001.png to ????????.png and sum with the audio to build a video. Notice how I use `%%` instead of `%`, try this too because sinse you are on Windows it matters. Also, I had to put ffmpeg.exe in the PHP folder in order to work properly. For some reason on Windows it will not run commands even if you specify the full path.

Comment: Although this is not related to your issue: option placement matters. You're attempting to apply `-qscale 2` to the input/decoder which does not make sense. `ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output`

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but I don't have any ffmpeg.exe file